# How to draw a separator across a panel using MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

This is a MigLayout-newbie question. I'd like to know how to draw a separator from the end of a label across the width of a panel.

Here's my example code:

```
package com.ndh.swingjunk;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyJFrame() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("foo");
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        JLabel anotherLabel = new JLabel("some other label");
        anotherLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        JButton button1 = new JButton("button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("button 2");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(separator, "growx, wrap");
        panel.add(anotherLabel);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        pack();
    }
}

public class SeparatorLayoutQuestion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {new MyJFrame().setVisible(true);}});}}
```

and here's the result:

[image: image of messed-up layout]

which is terribly lame. I'd like the separator to stretch from the end of "Foo" to the end of the panel, all the way across button 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what worked for me, I had to use "split" so the label and separator could share the same cell:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
panel.add(label, "split 2, span");
panel.add(separator, "growx, wrap");
panel.add(anotherLabel);
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button2);
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
 "span 3"
```

to the first label